# how can i fix this issue aboute this command in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.1, which is behind the latest release (4.0.2).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
not working these command

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

Comment: Is it that you can't run either of those commands? Or uninstalling create-react-app isn't working? Can you clarify what the issue is? Please be more specific than "it's not working".

Comment: What exactly happens when you do run those commands?